# C eror in comparing 3 numbers (1 of them is negative)

Tags: c

it would be nice if someone would help me with my code .
According to task i have a few numbers (at least 1 negative) in case i`m getting 3 numbers > 0 or = 0 then answer is 0 .Cod should find the closest to 0 number. Here is my cod but it is not working .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    int uno, dos, tres; //numbers


    printf("enter your numbers");
    scanf_s("%d %d %d", &uno, &dos, &tres);
    if (uno > 0 || uno == 0 && dos > 0 || dos == 0 && tres > 0 || tres == 0)
        printf("There is no negative numbers ...");
    else if (uno == 0 || uno > 0 && dos > 0 || dos == 0 && tres < 0)
        printf("Your number is %d", &tres);
    else if (uno > 0 || uno == 0 && dos < 0 && tres < 0)
        if (dos < tres || tres == dos)
            printf("Your number is %d", &tres);
        else
            printf("Your number is %d", &dos);
    else if (uno < 0 && dos < 0 && tres < 0)
        if (uno < dos && uno < tres)
            if (dos < tres || tres == dos)
                printf("Your number is %d", &tres);
            else printf("Your number is %d", dos);
        else if (dos < uno && dos < tres)
            if (uno < tres|| uno==tres)
                printf("Your number is %d",& tres);
            else printf("Your number is %d", &uno);
        else if (tres < uno && tres < dos)
            if (uno < dos || uno==dos)
                printf("Your number is %d",&dos);
            else printf("Your number id %d",&uno);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer site, and “it is not working” is not a question. What is the “eror”? [Learn how to use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Show examples of output and what do you want to be the output, error if any, and question for the real problem if possible. And improve your code, is almost impossible to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logical OR (||) has greater precedence than logical AND (&&) so you should add some parenthesis.
eg.

```
if (uno > 0 || uno == 0 && dos > 0 || dos == 0 && tres > 0 || tres == 0)
```

should become

```
if ((uno > 0 || uno == 0) && (dos > 0 || dos == 0) && (tres > 0 || tres == 0))
```

Comment: If he means those conditions, it should be `if(uno >= 0 && dos >= 0 && tres >=0)`

Comment: Yes it is a lot better that way but I thought it was more important to see what is going on with II and &&.
It should be those conditions by the description of the problem and the output printed.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple !

let say we have a, b and c. How to simply detect who is the lowest ?
Maybe We could use a variable to stock the minimal value that we could call min.

First let say we have only one number to test so the lowest number is the only one we have... so min <= a.

now add b and c to this problem.

We need to compare min and b, and put min <= b if b is lower than min. Then We just need to do the same for c, we could continue like that forever.

Your goal is to take the closest to 0, if I understand what you say. So just compare the absolute value of number and stock the real value to min.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int a = 0;
  int b = -1;
  int c = 2;

  int min = a;

  if (abs(min) > abs(b)) {
    min = b;
  }

  if (abs(min) > abs(c)) {
    min = c;
  }

  printf("min = %d\n", min);

  return 0;
}
```

If you have to do it for a lot of value have a look  [here](http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-arrays-example/) you would learn array in C who can solve this problem very easily.

---

```
printf("Your number is %d", &tres)
```

you have a big error here you not send the value of "tres" but his adresse. %d expect a **int** not a **int *** some doc [here](http://boredzo.org/pointers/)